# Why does my JFileChooser appear, but is empty?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser, rhino

I am making a Swing application by scripting Java via Rhino JS. I have a `JMenuItem` called `open` that I set an `ActionListener` that should cause a `JFileChooser` dialog to appear, and then I can work with the results. The code used to make the `JFileChooser` is:

```
  open.addActionListener(function(event) {
    var fileChooser = new JFileChooser()
    fileChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG)

    print(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) // Prints true

    var result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame) // frame is a closure variable

    if(result === JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      print("You have chosen a file!")
    }
  })
```

Now, when the `open` `JMenuItem` is clicked, the event fires correctly, and the `JFileChooser` does open, but it is completely blank as seen in the screenshot below:

Has anyone ever experienced this before? Any ideas? I'd gladly give more details if needed.
[image]

As @Antoniossss mentioned, resizing the `JFileChooser` does cause random black areas.
[image]

Comment: *frame is a closure variable*  I am not sure what this means, but can you try using `null` instead for the argument and see if the same thing happens?

Comment: @Compass > Well, by that I mean that it is the root `JFrame`, but it is passed in to function where this code is included, and so the anonymous function can reference it. I tried your suggestion, but there was no change. :(

Comment: Is the GUI responsive after popup? I mean can you resize, move something, close the dialog? Looks like internal event loop is not fired - not sure why.

Comment: @Antoniossss > The entire GUI is responsive after the popup. Both dialog and parent frame can be resized/closed, and I get no exceptions on the command line. I can give more details if I need.

Comment: @Miguel then it is really strange. If GUI is responsive then everything should work as expected. One more shot is to try to remove `fileChooser.setDialogType(JFileChooser.OPEN_DIALOG)`

Comment: @Antoniossss > Tried it, and still no go. :( Could it possibly be an issue with my JRE installation? I'm going to try this code on another computer, and see what happens.

Comment: Code looks ok at the first glance - there must be some exception thrown.

Comment: @Antoniossss > Is it possible that I wouldn't be seeing them? I mean, I'm not catching anything, and when there is other problems they print out at the console. Here it's totally blank...

Comment: @Miguel ye, it should be printed to stderr - in your case most probably the console. The only thing you can to is to wrap this into `try-catch` block,  catch `Throwable` and see it someyhing is thrown indeed. No other ideas (or maybe im just tired and not seeing one)

Comment: @Antoniossss > Okay, I wrapped a try-catch around it, and nothing. Definitely no exceptions are being thrown. The only thing would be that this specific exception would not be noticed by Rhino, but considering I get every other Java exception fine, I don't see why it would...

Comment: @Miguel I am out of ideas. It is hard to break something in practicly 2 relevant lines of code. SaveFile shows like that as well? Is the dialog resizable? Is it repains - or black areas appears while resizing? And in such hopeless situations checking on different JRE is also worh of trying. Any other popup windows works fine? SaveFile or OptionPane and yes/no popups?

I am asking about resizing and stuff because it looks like there is no internal event loop - and this would cause such behavior including no repaints on resize. Internal event loop is like local EDT for that concrete dialog

Comment: @Antoniossss First off, thank you so much for the help already. Means a lot :) Now, I did find that resizing the `JFileChooser` causes black areas. I added a screenshot above. Currently working through your other suggestions.

Comment: @Miguel and for the sake of clarity and to be 1000% sure we are on the same page, if you do `throw new RuntimeException("justme");` just before ` var result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(frame)` you will see that the exception has been raised right? Sorry for beeing pain in the ars but exception is the only reasonable explanation to me - unless rhino interfears with Swing internals somehow

Comment: @Miguel The last thing you can do if it is possible, is to use debugger, step into `showOpenDialog` and check why component is not painted.

Comment: @Antoniossss > Okay, so throwing the exception you mentioned resulted it in being both caught by a try-catch, as well as going out on console (stderr) if left uncaught. I tried a YES_NO_OPTION dialogue, and similar to this, it was left blank. Interesting, clicking the right areas causes the dialogue to function correcty! It's working, its just not showing up! I could use a debugger if I have to.

Comment: I can also confirm that the `JFileChooser` also works correctly, it just doesn't render anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. On the command line to invoke Rhino I had `-Dsun.java2d.opengl=true`. This was left over from an older project, and seemed to cause conflict with something on my system. Removing it fixed the problem. Many thanks to @Antoniossss for guiding me in the right direction!

Comment: That is something I would never came up with ;) g2k you are done.